# ClassName() did not return any, snippet tool visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, code-snippets

I am trying to use snippet tool in visual studio to generate a copyright text in each file. I created a snippet file as follow:

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0"  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <Header>
        <Title>Copyright (c) 2014, CompanyName</Title>
        <Description>License applies to this software </Description>
      <Author>CompanyName</Author>
      <Shortcut>Copyright</Shortcut>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
        <Declarations>
            <Literal Editable="false">
                <ID>classname</ID> 
                <ToolTip>Class name</ToolTip> 
                <Function>ClassName()</Function> 
            </Literal>
        </Declarations>
        <Code Language="CSharp">
            <![CDATA[
             /*Copyright file $classname$

             *
             *Copyright (c) 2015, CompanyName
             *
             *Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
             *
             *1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
             *
             *2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation and/or other 
             *materials provided with the distribution.
             *
             *3. Neither the name of the copyright holder nor the names of its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software without specific 
             *prior written permission.

             *THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
             *PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. *IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF *SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, *DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE)
             *ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED *OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
             */]]>
        </Code>
    </Snippet>
</CodeSnippet>
```

However the ClassName() function did not return any Class name when I am insert this code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see your problem now. If you add your snippet inside of the class this will work. If you insert this outside of your class on the top this can't work because the class is not the context of the snippet.

Comment: then it replaced by this ClassNamePlaceholder, but I need the class name

Comment: I see :D, it will be better if they have a function for calling the file name.